# Is there a method to install peer dependencies of dependencies?

Tags: dependencies

On running npm install, we get this:

```
npm WARN ajv-keywords@2.1.1 requires a peer of ajv@^5.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself
```

Our initial belief was that the issue was a need to install the peer dependency mentioned - `ajv` - but that has not fixed the problem.

The important thing is simply understanding the issue. What does the error message even mean, given that we do have the dependencies satisfied AFAICT?

package.json has this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "ajv": "^6.0.0"
  },
```

package-lock.json has this:

```
    "ajv": {
      "version": "6.2.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv/-/ajv-6.2.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-KKarxJOiq+D7TIUHrK7bQ/pVBnE=",
      "requires": {
        "fast-deep-equal": "1.1.0",
        "fast-json-stable-stringify": "2.0.0",
        "json-schema-traverse": "0.3.1"
      }
    },
    "ajv-keywords": {
      "version": "2.1.1",
      "resolved": "https://registry.npmjs.org/ajv-keywords/-/ajv-keywords-2.1.1.tgz",
      "integrity": "sha1-YXmX/F9gV2iUxDX5QNgZ4TW4B2I=",
      "dev": true
    }
```

`npm-install-peers` gives

```
This package doesn't seem to have any peerDependencies
```

The maintainer of that tool says

> It's designed to install the direct peer dependencies of your project,
> not the peer dependencies of your dependencies

which means the issue is a dependency deeper than the top level.

Is there a tool to install the dependencies of dependencies?

Comment: did you ever resolve this? I have the same issue with a couple of packages

Comment: Was this ever solved? @ekkis

Comment: See other commenters below.

Comment: @ChristopherMartinez I abandoned npm in favour of yarn which seems to do a better job with this stuff

Answer (score 9):

Install the specific version of AJV that's being requested:

```
npm install ajv@^5.0.0 --save
```

(the `^` ensures that only minor, backward compatible updates will be installed for the package e.g. 5.1.0)

Comment: When I follow this suggestion, the message is gone, but I then get this instead: `ajv-keywords@3.4.1 requires a peer of ajv@^6.9.1`, If I install that, we go back to the initial message. How can this be solved?

Comment: I think you need to install a different version of ajv-keywords. You'll need to find out which version is compatible with the version of AJV you've installed

Answer (score 5):

I'm using firebase-admin and this issue poped as well, when I've updated to the version 7.0.0 of firebase-admin.

I've explicitly specified the latest version for both components and the warning is gone :

```
"ajv": "^6.10.0",
"ajv-keywords": "^3.4.0"
```

Comment: This solved the issue for me, it is funny how we don't have automated solutions for these problems in a mature ecosystem such as npm

Answer (score 1):

Looking at https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9691 there's suggestions this is a problem with recent versions of npm. Deleting package-lock.json corrected this error for me.

Comment: Deleting package-lock.json and running npm install fixed it for me too.